# plot(x,y) is showing an empty graph

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to plot a simple function on matlab but it's showing an empty graph.

```
x=0.001:1;
y=15/x;

figure
plot(x,y)
xlabel('Pr/Pn (dB)')
ylabel('Processing gains (dB)')
```

here is what I got:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only plot one point, the point (0.001, 15/0.001) = (x, y).
You probably want something like:

```
x = 0:0.001:1
y = 15./x
figure
plot(x,y)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all `x=0.001:1` produces you a single value but not an array.Change it to `x=0:0.001:1`.

Second of all  `y=15./x` will give you an infinity as the x(1)=0 and you get a division by zero.

Finally:

```
x_n=x(2:end); % taking out first 0 term
y=15./x_n(2:end);
plot(x,y)
```

[image]